# For loop with involving data from forms (form.array[i].checked)

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm making a website that has a user order a pizza. I am using a form to collect all the data and am having troubles with my JavaScript.

```
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="cheeseCheckbox" value="cheese" onclick="toppingAddedRemoved(this.form)" />Cheese<br />
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="pepperoniCheckbox" value="pepperoni" />Pepperoni<br />
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="hamCheckbox" value="ham" />Ham<br />
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="pineappleCheckbox" value="pineapple" />Pineapple<br />
```

This is the relevant HTML that I am trying to get data from. I'm currently only testing with the first input.

```
function getToppings(form){
    var toppingsNames = new Array("cheeseCheckbox", "pepperoniCheckbox", "hamCheckbox");
    var toppings = new Array();
    var numberOfToppings = 0;
    var i;
    // writeToDIV(form.cheeseCheckbox.checked);
    for (i in toppingsNames){
        if (form.toppingsNames[i].checked === true){
            toppings.push(form.toppingsNames[i].value);
            numberOfToppings++;
        }
    }
    // if (form.cheeseCheckbox.checked === true){
    //   toppings.push(form.cheeseCheckbox.value);
    //   numberOfToppings++;
    // }else if (form.Checkbox.checked === true)
    // writeToDIV(toppings + numberOfToppings);
}
```

My JavaScript here at the bottom with the if statement is working but that would be tedious set if statements for all of my checkboxes.

My thought was to use a for loop that that replaces the name in the code

```
form.INPUTNAME.checked
```

with `form.toppingsNames[i].input`.

This however doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can loop this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to do this would be to give the checkboxes all the same name. That way you can select the checkboxes from the markup without recreating them in the js. Since they are all the same name, you can simply grab the checkboxes that are checked and loop through those.

This will also make it easier when submitting your form to the server since languages like PHP will be able to read the values based on the name. (In this case $_POST['toppings'])

```js
function saveToppings() {
  var checkedToppings = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='toppings']:checked");
  var usersToppings = [];
  for(i = 0; i < checkedToppings.length; i++) {
    usersToppings.push(checkedToppings[i].value);
  }
  if(usersToppings.length < 1) {
    document.getElementById('savedToppings').innerHTML = 'No toppings selected';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('savedToppings').innerHTML = usersToppings;
  }
}
(function(){
  document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', saveToppings);
})();
```

```html
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="cheese" />Cheese<br />
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="pepperoni" />Pepperoni<br />
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="ham" />Ham<br />
<input class="customCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="pineapple" />Pineapple<br />
<button id="save">Save toppings</button>
<div id="savedToppings"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll explain why your current code doesn't work.

The error stems from the `toppingsNames[i]` in `form.toppingsNames[i]`

This is being interpreted as an attempt to get the index `i` of an array named `toppingsNames` that is a property of the object `form`, however form has no such property.

I have some example code to help explain.

```
    var foo = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};
    var bar = ["a", "b", "c"];

    //The following will cause TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    //It will not output 2
    console.log(foo.bar[1]);

    //This will output '2'
    console.log(foo.b)        

    //Instead, access the value like this
    //This will output '2'
    console.log(foo[bar[1]]);
```

`form[toppingsNames[i]]` should output a property of form named `toppingsNames[i]`'s value, which is what you are looking for.

`form[toppingsNames[i]].value` should evaluate to either `true` or `false`